# What combinations of ram can I put in my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, 64-bit

Here's my laptop:

**Dell Precision M6500 (Quad Core) Laptop/Notebook**

http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/viewscanbyid.aspx?id=4A6D63E631D926C3

I'm running windows 7, enterprise, 64 bit

According to this I can support up to 192GB of ram:
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/max-memory-limits-for-64-bit-windows-7/4254

**Can I put 4x48gb sticks in? What about 2x16gb and 2x2gb? How do I know which combinations are OK?**

Comment: The OS can support up to enormous, even to the point of never will use RAM, as long as all the ram is the same type and what the system can use, ddr2, ddr3, then you can use RAM at any clock speed, the only other dependent is the board itself, certain boards can only use modules of ram so big, older computers are usually 512-1gig most newer, around 2-3 years old, support up to 4 gig sticks, the best way is to do a quick google search of the specs of the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your information is here: http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/viewscanbyid.aspx?id=4A6D63E631D926C3

Where you linked to.

> Memory Type: DDR3 PC3-10600, DDR3 PC3-12800, DDR3 PC3-14900, DDR3
>   (non-ECC) Maximum Memory: 32GB Slots: 4

The OS at this point is only future proofed. 64bit can support up to 16 exabytes, Win 7 192GB, but consumer machines have neither now, or anytime soon.

Comment: i've upgraded to 2.5 exabytes for my farm

Answer (score 1):

Go to Dell's support site.  Per the tech manual, the system can support up to 32G.  It can accept 1G, 2G, 4G, 8G modules and can aparently take 4 modules.

ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_precision_mobile/precision-m6500_service%20manual_en-us.pdf